# Mapping a texture from "1D" to "2D" with OpenGL matrix transformations

Tags: android, opengl-es, matrix-transform

*(With this question I'm trying to investigate an idea I had for solving [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30361198/efficient-algorithm-for-2d-memory-management))*

If I have a standard 2D array of dimensions *width* and *height* in memory, I can turn that into a 1D array of length *width* * *height* and then index it via *index* = *x* + *y* * *width*. This mapping is extremely helpful when allocating and freeing memory for the array as the memory manager does not need to worry about packing the structures in 2D but only needs to worry about the overall length of every allocated array if expressed in 1D.

I am trying to see if I can use this same approach for image-memory management for OpenGL textures. The idea (as described in the above linked question) is to combine a whole bunch of needed textures into a single bigger one by [bin-packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) them (i.e. drawing them next to each other) into the big texture. This helps minimize costly texture-binding operations during rendering.

Let's say my big texture is 8×8 pixels (i.e. 64 pixels total):

```
8x8 texture:                5x5 image:            4x5 image:

   | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7           | 0 1 2 3 4           | 0 1 2 3
---+-----------------       ---+-----------       ---+---------
 0 | . . . . . . . .         0 | A B C D E         0 | a b c d
 1 | . . . . . . . .         1 | F G H I J         1 | e f g h
 2 | . . . . . . . .         2 | K L M N O         2 | i j k l
 3 | . . . . . . . .         3 | P Q R S T         3 | m n o p
 4 | . . . . . . . .         4 | U V W X Y         4 | q r s t
 5 | . . . . . . . .
 6 | . . . . . . . .
 7 | . . . . . . . .
```

And I would like to store a 5×5 image and a 4×5 image in it (i.e. 25 + 20 = 45 pixels total). Technically, I have plenty of pixels available, but I can't place these images next to each other into the big texture as that would require a minimum dimension of 9 in one direction and 5 in the other.

If I could simply treat my 8×8 texture as 64 continues pixels of memory and map the two images into 1D blocks of memory inside that, I could arrange the images as follows inside the texture:
    8x8 texture:

```
   | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
---+-----------------
 0 | A B C D E F G H
 1 | I J K L M N O P             
 2 | Q R S T U V W X
 3 | Y a b c d e f g             
 4 | h i j k l m n o             
 5 | p q r s t . . .
 6 | . . . . . . . .
 7 | . . . . . . . .
```

If I draw all my images at a scale of 1:1, i.e. no fractional pixel coordinates anywhere and no need for any linear filtering or other pixel blending, is it possible to come up with a transformation matrix that I can use to draw the 4×5 image using this texture?

With vertex and fragment shaders, this looks like it might be fairly easy (unless I'm forgetting something; I haven't tried this):

- The vertex shader maps the four corners of the image to draw to the texture expressed as a 64×1 image:

  - `a`: (0, 0) → (0 + 0*4 + 25, 0) = (25, 0)     where 25 is the offset of the 4×5 image
  - `d`: (3, 0) → (3 + 0*4 + 25, 0) = (28, 0)
  - `q`: (0, 4) → (0 + 4*4 + 25, 0) = (41, 0)
  - `t`: (3, 4) → (3 + 4*4 + 25, 0) = (44, 0)

  The interpolation of other coordinates inside the texture *should* (?) then also map to the right offset along this line for integer coordinates
- The fragment shader converts this 64×1-coordinate into the final 8×8 coordinate by simply taking the quotient and remainder of a division by 8, e.g.:

  - `a`: (0, 25) → (25 % 8, 25 / 8) = (1, 3)
  - `d`: (0, 28) → (28 % 8, 28 / 8) = (4, 3)
  - `k`: (0, 35) → (35 % 8, 35 / 8) = (3, 4)
  - `q`: (0, 41) → (41 % 8, 41 / 8) = (1, 5)
  - `t`: (0, 44) → (44 % 8, 44 / 8) = (4, 5)

Unfortunately custom shaders require OpenGL ES v2.0 or better, which is not available on all devices.

Is it somehow possible to achieve this mapping just via the matrix transformations offered by OpenGL ES 1.1?

Comment: Note that the percentage of active devices that do not support at least ES 2.0 has fallen so low that Google stopped tracking it (http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards). I believe it was about 1-2% when they last published numbers for ES 1.1. I would actually be more concerned about how well the ES 1.1 implementations on newer devices still work, considering how obsolete it is.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is not, as that wouldn't be an linear transformation and therefore can't be represented by a matrix.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Good point. I should definitely check out the performance implications. In general I try to support as many devices as possible unless it causes issues on more modern ones. I'd be surprised, though, if the standard matrix transforms had gotten slower on modern devices. It's still the standard way to do things, no?

Comment: @chbaker0 I'm not quite sure where you see a non-linearity. Did you mean the modulus operation that I put in the fragment shader part? Maybe that one is achievable by turning on texture wrapping (GL_REPEAT)?

Comment: @chbaker0 I guess there is also the implicit rounding on the division... That might be a tougher one. Is it possible to use integer vectors (rather than floats) to force the rounding somehow? Wait... That should be doable via nearest neighbor pixel selection rules rather than a some linear filtering... Would just have to subtract 0.5 so that it rounds down correctly... Could that work?

Comment: The implicit modulus in texture wrapping is applied per-axis though, and after the transformation, and can't move to the next row of the texture (which would be necessary for what you're suggesting). The matrix multiplication on the texture coordinates is always done in floating point, and without respect to any parameters of the texture.

Comment: @chbaker0 I wrote up a quick idea on what this might look like (see below). Does this look correct to you?

Comment: index = x + y * height should be index = x + y * width

Comment: @samgak Of course! Sorry! :) Fixed...

Comment: packing textures in this way completely ruins caching optimizations and hardware interpolation, you should not be doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this yet, but I wanted to throw it out there as an idea already:

***UPDATE: I tried it now and it works beautifully with one minor change (see comment)!***

Let's say my big texture has width `size` and the image I want to draw has width `width` and starts at offset `offset` inside the big texture, where `offset` is the 1-D representation of the offset, i.e. `x` + `y` * `size`.

Then, the following 4x4 matrix will almost achieve this mapping:

```
     _                                           _
    |      1        width        offset      0    |
    |                                             |
    |   1/size   width/size   offset/size    0    |
M = |                                             |
    |      0          0            0         0    |
    |                                             |
    |_     0          0            0         1   _|
```

So, in the example above, to draw the 4×5 image, the matrix would be

```
 _                    _
|   1    4    25    0  |
|  1/8  1/2  25/8   0  |
|   0    0     0    0  |
|_  0    0     0    1 _|
```

The image coordinates will then need to be specified with a 4-vector containing

```
( x, y, 1, 1 )
```

So, for example the coordinates of `k` (i.e. (2,2)) will map to:

```
M*( 2, 2, 1, 1 ) => ( 35, 4.375, 0, 1 )
```

which will be interpreted as texture coordinate (35, 4.375).

If we now turn on nearest neighbor as the interpolation rule and enable texture wrapping in the x-direction, this should correspond to:

```
( 3, 4 )
```

(I was using integer coordinates here, whereas in the final implementation, the final coordinates would need to be floats in the range from 0 to 1. This might be achievable very easily by replacing the `1` in the bottom right corner of the matrix with `size`, since that will end up in the fourth position of the output vector and thus divide the other three. This, as @chbaker0 pointed out, would only work, though, if the texture coordinates are subject to the usual perspective division. If they are not, the entire matrix `M` needs to be divided by `size` instead to achieve the desired result.)

Does this sound reasonable at all or can someone see a problem with this before I go ahead and try to implement this? (Might take me a few days, since I have to do a couple other things first to get to a testable app...)

Comment: "This can actually be achieved very easily by replacing the 1 in the bottom right corner of the matrix with size, since that will end up in the fourth position of the output vector and thus divide the other three." I'm not sure if texture coordinates are subject to perspective division. The spec isn't too clear on it either: https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/1.1/es_full_spec_1.1.12.pdf section 2.10. I read through it, and from my reading I gather that it is *not* subject to perspective division.

Comment: @chbaker0 Awesome! I've been having a lot of trouble finding a good reference manual. This seems like a great one! Thanks for the link! If the texture coordinates are not subject to perspective division, all that needs to be done is to divide the entire matrix by `size` instead of replacing the bottom right `1`. So that shouldn't be a deal-breaker either way... But I'll make a note of it in the answer.

Comment: It's the best one, it's the official OpenGL ES 1.1 Specification published by Khronos :) I'll try to work some stuff out on paper tomorrow because while my gut says it can't be done with matrices, you have good points.

Comment: @chbaker0 :) That would be awesome, thanks! If this works, this could be hugely beneficial for performance of dynamic texture generating apps, I'd think.

Comment: @chbaker0 Just tried this out: It works beautifully! :) Just one change needed: OpenGL seems to add 0.5 to the y-coordinate of texture coordinates, so to get `k` in the example above, one needs to specify (2, 1.5) instead. Or, one could probably adjust the matrix to take care of this.